# htaccess rewrite rule test for http elements requested

Tags: .htaccess, http, https

How can I test if the request is from http URL (even though https may be on). I want to serve https page elements if https is turned on.

Answer (score 2):

One common method is to use RewriteCond to check if the HTTPS env var is on or off (on=https, off=http). For example, this checks if the request came in over http, and if it did, returns a 403 Forbidden:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

this requires the rewrite module to be enabled.

**UPDATED** (Additional Examples)

Force all page elements to https if the page itself (referer) is on https:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https:
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Or if you knew it was only image (file types) you needed to catch, you could make the RewriteRule more efficient, like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https:
RewriteRule ^.*\.(gif|png|jpe?g)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: The page is using https but the image being loaded is using http. How can I test for this?

Comment: Your initial question was how to "test" if request was http or https, but I wasn't sure what you wanted to do with that test. Think I have a clearer picture now. You're wanting to make sure the requests for sub elements are redirected to https if the page itself is https. I updated the answer with another example.